# Period of a trigonometric series

Tags: periodic-functions

What is the period of the function represented by the series

$a_1 cos x+a_2cos2x+a_3cos3x+...$

I guess it is $2\pi$. Am I right?

Comment: If the series is infinite, then it may not even converge.

Comment: Yes, assuming the sum exists.

Comment: @Paul Actually, the period is *at most* $2\pi$, but it can be smaller in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not right, not in general.

First of all, the series in question may not even converge so talking about its period would make no sense. But let's assume the series converges to a function $f(x)$

The period is **at most** $2\pi$, in the sense that $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$ without a doubt. But, for example, if $a_1=a_3=a_4=\dots=0$, then $f(x+\pi)=f(x)$ as well, and the period of $f$ is $\pi$.

Comment: $a_4$ or $a_5$?

Comment: @user3575652 $a_5$, as in "all $a_i$ except for $a_2$".